# grunt-cssc not working "cannot read property 'type'" ~ Foundation 5

Tags: css, gruntjs, zurb-foundation

I am having trouble using grunt-cssc in my Foundation 5 framework.

Error:

```
Running "cssc:build" <cssc> task
Warning: cannot read property 'type' of undefined use --force to continue.
```

My Code:

```
cssc: {
        build: {
            files: {
                'css/app.css': 'css/app.css'
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was most probably conflicting with libsass or something else from Foundation side.

I solved it by adding options and setting **"sortDeclarations", "consolidateViaSelectors", "consolidateMediaQueries"** to **false**.

```
cssc: {
        build: {
            options: {
                sortSelectors: true,
                    lineBreaks: true,
                    sortDeclarations:true,
                    consolidateViaDeclarations:false,
                    consolidateViaSelectors:false,
                    consolidateMediaQueries:false,
            },
            files: {
                'css/app.css': 'css/app.css'
            }
        }
    },
```